# Solving list of expressions in sympy

Tags: python, sympy

I have list of expression in the form.

```
f1 = q1 * f2 + r1
f2 = q2 * r1 + r2
r1 = q3 * r2 + r3
r2 = q4 * r3 + r4
```

I would like to express `r4` in terms of `f1`, `f2` and `qn`(i.e. q1, q2, ...). How can i perform this operation in sympy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sympy.solve` can be passed a list of expressions (equal to zero) and a list of Symbols to be solved for. If there is a solution, it is returned in a dict.
Since you seek a solution in terms of the `f`s and `q`s, solve for all of the `r` variables.

```
f1, f2, r1, r2, r3, r4, q1, q2, q3, q4 = sy.symbols('f1,f2,r1,r2,r3,r4,q1,q2,q3,q4')
ans = sy.solve([
    f1 - q1 * f2 - r1,
    f2 - q2 * r1 - r2,
    r1 - q3 * r2 - r3,
    r2 - q4 * r3 - r4], [r4, r3, r2, r1])
print(ans[r4])
```

prints

```
f2*(q3*q4 + 1) - (f1 - f2*q1)*(q2*q3*q4 + q2 + q4)
```